# MySQL workbench status "STARTING" not started

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench refused to start. The status shown is "starting". I cannot stop it at all as there is no button where I can click. I tried to shut down my PC and wait for awhile but it still refused to start. The status remained starting. I look at other similar problem with me but it is not helpful enough. Anyone know what is the problem?

I am using Windows XP and MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE

Answer (score 0):

According to the requirements-page of MySQL-Workbench [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-requirements.html), it states under the section "Requirements for Windows" the following:

- Windows 7 and above

And there is also a note:

> MySQL Workbench 6.1 supports earlier versions of Windows, including Vista

But it doesn't sound like XP is still supported.

Also, [you really shouldn't be using XP anymore right now](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/end-of-xp-support). Seriously.

Comment: Actually it is not my pc. Its my office pc.My supervisor used it to test system as that the only pc that available in my office . But currently, i cannot do anything because MySQL refused to start.